# Is there a word for repeating the last letter of an acronym?

Tags: terminology

Sometimes I find myself noticing people saying things like

> […] CLI interface.

Since CLI already stands for *command-line interface*, repeating the last letter of the acronym in its expanded form is redundant.

Is there a name for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I found the answer: [RAS Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome):

> RAS syndrome (short for "redundant acronym syndrome syndrome") refers
>   to the use of one or more of the words that make up an acronym or
>   initialism in conjunction with the abbreviated form, thus in effect
>   repeating one or more words.

Comment: I guess what happens is the acronym becomes lexicalised, and is treated as a single, opaque expression (even tho people will mostly be able to unpack it if asked), so where the generic is included in the acronym it will commonly be repeated in the way described, e.g. 'ATM machine'.

Comment: Or PIN number or GUI interface or ECM module

Comment: Conversely, D-Day and H-Hour, where D and H just stood for Day and Hour.